# set image icon in android material designed tabs instead of just title

Tags: android

I want to set an image icon in place of title in material designed tab.

I am using `android.support.design.widget.Tab` Layout. Please help me to set an icon in every tab.

Please do not provide a solution using sliding tab Layout, because I also want to implement collapsing action bar style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest Android Design Support Library by Google. You can follow **[this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs)** tutorial to get icons only tab.